# how to visit the angular app in production

Tags: angular, production

I am using angular 8 to build a application with root routing config as below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'index', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/index/index.module').then(mod => mod.IndexModule) },
];
```

in the development mode, it is available to visit the index page by

> http://localhost:4200/index

now the project is built through the command  `ng build --prod`, and that produces a list of compiled files in dist folder

I put the dist folder in a node.js project 's public folder

```
--node.js app
   --  public
   --  express.js :3000 port
```

but I tried to visit the angular app by

```
http://localhost:3000/dist/index.html#/index
```

the browser tells me

GET http://localhost:3000/dist/index.html 500 (Internal Server Error)

why is that , how to solve it ?

Comment: where did you host

Comment: @Sajeetharan I host in the local node.js server